# how to change table data on checked row using jquery

Tags: jquery

So, this is my table

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb1"></td>
  <td class="cn">a1<td>
  <td>b1<td>
  <td>c1<td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb2"></td>
  <td class="cn">a1<td>
  <td>b1<td>
  <td>c1<td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb3"></td>
  <td class="cn">a1<td>
  <td>b1<td>
  <td>c1<td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

popup code:

```
<label>Line Number</label>
<input type="text"  id="line-no">
<button type="button"  id="update">Update</button>
```

when i select any row and give input on a popup that i have created and click update,i want to change the table data with the id "cn" into the input i have provided in the popup for the corresponding checked rows.All this using jquery.

Comment: `id` is meant to be unique. Use `class` if you want to have the same identifier

Comment: you should use class if same name.

Comment: Also, where is the code for popup and that you have tried so far?

Comment: please clarify what you want to do....

Comment: if suppose i check cb1 and cb2 check boxes and give a2 as line number on pop up and update ..i want the checked rows that is ,the first two rows a1 needs to be changed as a2

Answer (score 2):

Please check this

```js
var checkedRows = [];

$('#eventsTable').on('check.bs.table', function (e, row) {
  checkedRows.push({id: row.id, name: row.name, forks: row.forks});
  console.log(checkedRows);
});

$('#eventsTable').on('uncheck.bs.table', function (e, row) {
  $.each(checkedRows, function(index, value) {
    if (value.id === row.id) {
      checkedRows.splice(index,1);
    }
  });
  console.log(checkedRows);
});

$("#add_cart").click(function() {
  $("#output").empty();
  $.each(checkedRows, function(index, value) {
    $('#output').append($('<li></li>').text(value.id + " | " + value.name + " | " + value.forks));
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.8.1/bootstrap-table.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.8.1/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

<table id="eventsTable"
       data-toggle="table"
       data-height="300"
       data-url="https://api.github.com/users/wenzhixin/repos?type=owner&sort=full_name&direction=asc&per_page=100&page=1"
       data-pagination="true"
       data-search="true"
       data-show-refresh="true"
       data-show-toggle="true"
       data-show-columns="true"
       data-toolbar="#toolbar">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
        <th data-field="name">Name</th>
        <th data-field="stargazers_count">Stars</th>
        <th data-field="forks_count">Forks</th>
        <th data-field="description">Description</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<button id="add_cart">Add to card</button>
<ul id="output"></ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please Try Below Js :

```
$("#update").click(function(){
  $("table").find("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')==true){
      var txt_value = $("#line-no").val();
      if(txt_value != ""){
          $(this).closest("tr").find("td.cn").text(txt_value);
      }

    } 
  });
});
```

Please Check Html there is Change Only Id To Class :

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox"id="cb1"></td>
  <td class="cn">a1<td>
  <td>b1<td>
  <td>c1<td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb2"></td>
  <td class="cn">a2<td>
  <td>b2<td>
  <td>c2<td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb3"></td>
  <td class="cn">a3<td>
  <td>b3<td>
  <td>c3<td>
 </tr>
</table>
<label>Line Number</label>
<input type="text"  id="line-no">
<button type="button"  id="update">Update</button>
```

Comment: bear with me i am a beginner.which jquery version?